# MVC Helper class access in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a `detailpage.cshtml` file in App_code

```
@helper convertTime(DateTime value)
    {
        value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

and am trying to access this in my view  but am not able to access this in my view.

Am i missing something ?

i referred http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx but still am not getting what i am missing ?

Comment: How do you try to access it? With `@detailpage.convertTime`?

Comment: yes. But not accessible

Comment: Have you added a reference the namespace YourAppName.App_Code with `@using YourAppName.App_Code`? And can you post what is the exact error message when calling `@detailpage.convertTime`?

Comment: i restarted  and  re build and itz working now. Thanks